# How to do Geo IP or postcode lookup against Geonames data

Tags: autocomplete, geoip, postal-code, geonames

I am using the freely available [geonames](http://geonames.org/) data locally to do autocomplete searches during the sign up stage on one of my websites.

I am having trouble working out the best way to make the form more user friendly by auto selecting a geoname based on their IP address and also be able to lookup a geoname based on the [postcode data](http://www.geonames.org/postal-codes/).

The problem is that I can't see a way to easily link an IP range or a postal code to a geoname.  So what is the best practice here?  Do I just run a separate query to lookup the nearest geoname by long/lat against the postcode or IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention how you are geolocating the IP address, but the MaxMind GeoIP2 and GeoLite2 databases provide the `geoname_id` of the location. See, e.g., the [CSV docs](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geoip2-csv-databases/). The binary databases provide this same information.

Comment: Ahh right,  I think I was looking at the legacy version which doesn't offer geoname_id.   Thanks I will take a look in more detail.